# Can I cook brown rice in broth?

Tags: rice

Can I make brown rice substituting chicken broth for water? How much of the chicken flavor transfers to the rice?

Comment: I edited your question to bring it in line with the Q&A format we expect here.

Answer (score 6):

There is no problem doing this, some flavour transfers to the rice as you'd expect. Try to measure the amount you use so the rice doesn't need draining (or just have it with the remaining liquid). And be careful with additional seasoning like salt if the broth is already salted.